# Download HTML file from jupyter-notebook to local

Tags: python, html, utf-8, jupyter-notebook

How to download a file from jupyter-notebook with a given pop up link ? I need this pop up link and click it to download it as a HTML file. I got a problem with the character `"` double quotes and `'`, these character made a trouble for my HTML code in order to make it a pop up of download. But, I need these character to keep it on my script without replacing with anything.

This is my HTML script:

```
<html>
<head><meta charset='utf-8' /></head>
<body>
<h3>You can "view" HTML code "in" notebooks. Result 'want to' get it '"' testing only</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code python script:

```
from IPython.display import FileLink, HTML

title = "Download HTML file"
filename = "data.html"

payload = open("./cobaan_html2.html").read()
payload = payload.replace('<meta charset="utf-8" />', "<meta charset='utf-8' />")
html = '<a download="{filename}" href="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,'+payload+'" target="_blank">{title}</a>'

print(payload)
HTML(html)
```

And this is what I got.

```
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
<body>
<h3>You can "view" HTML code "in" notebooks. Result 'want to' get it '"' testing only</h3>
</body>
</html>
You can "view" HTML code "in" notebooks. Result 'want to' get it '"' testing only
" target="_blank">{title}
```

With image result prove:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your quotes with their non-breaking HTML equivalents as follows:

1. `"` --> `&quot;`
2. `'` --> `&apos;`